# Unit testing CakePHP 3 plugin requires a config/routes.php folder to test with Router::url()

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, routes

I am writing some tests for a CakePHP 3 plugin, and some of my actions use `Router::url` calls. When I run phpunit I get the following error: `include([project dir]\\config\routes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

What I'd like to know is if this file is really required just for unit testing to work. If I create the file on that folder the testing works right. I have tried adding

`DispatcherFactory::add('Asset');
 DispatcherFactory::add('Routing');
 DispatcherFactory::add('ControllerFactory');`

to my `tests/bootstrap.php` file, however it did no change at all.

Since this is a standalone plugin I'd find it a little odd to have a `config` folder with a `routes.php` file in it for the sole purpose of testing. Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router requires a `routes.php` file to be present on application level, so what you should do is configure a test application environment where you can place such files.

In your `tests/bootstrap.php` file, define the required constants and configuration that your test environment needs. If it where just for the router, it would probably be enough if you'd define the `CONFIG` constant accordingly, which is being used in [**`\Cake\Routing\Router::_loadRoutes()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#1087-1097), like

```
define('CONFIG', dirname(__DIR__) . DS . 'tests' . DS . 'TestApp' . DS . 'config' . DS);
```

This would set the config dir to `tests/TestApp/config/`, where you could place the `routes.php` file.

Generally I'd recommend to setup all constants, and at least basic application configuration, here's an example from one of my plugins:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;

if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
define('APP_DIR', 'src');
define('APP_ROOT', ROOT . DS . 'tests' . DS . 'TestApp' . DS);
define('APP', APP_ROOT . APP_DIR . DS);
define('CONFIG', APP_ROOT . DS . 'config' . DS);
define('WWW_ROOT', APP . DS . 'webroot' . DS);
define('TESTS', ROOT . DS . 'tests' . DS);
define('TMP', APP_ROOT . DS . 'tmp' . DS);
define('LOGS', APP_ROOT . DS . 'logs' . DS);
define('CACHE', TMP . 'cache' . DS);
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'cakephp');
define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
define('CAKE', CORE_PATH . 'src' . DS);

require_once ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';
require_once CORE_PATH . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';

$config = [
    'debug' => true,

    'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'defaultLocale' => 'en_US',
        'base' => false,
        'baseUrl' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        'webroot' => 'webroot',
        'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
        'fullBaseUrl' => 'http://localhost',
        'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
        'paths' => [
            'plugins' => [APP_ROOT . 'plugins' . DS],
            'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
            'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
        ],
    ]
];
Configure::write($config);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
mb_internal_encoding(Configure::read('App.encoding'));
ini_set('intl.default_locale', Configure::read('App.defaultLocale'));

Plugin::load('MyPlugin', ['path' => ROOT]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for the detailed answer! I had set the `CONFIG` constant but was using the project root instead of the `tests` dir. The example config is pretty useful too.